# Ruby: How to Work With Class Vars in a Module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I always have a brain cramp when it comes to this. I'm creating a module to mix in to model-like classes but it needs to keep exactly one copy of serializable attributes per class. So here is the code (that doesn't work).

```
module Checkin
  module Model
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(ClassMethods)
    end

    @@serialiable_attrs = []   <== really not the right place
    module ClassMethods
      def serializable(*attrs)
        attrs.each{|attr| @@serializable_attrs << attr} # Is this @@ or just @?
      end
    end

    def serialize!
      @@serializable_attrs.each{|a| do_something_with(a)} # <== Will this work?
    end
  end
end

class Person  
  include Checkin::Model
  serializable :first_name, :original_name, :last_name, :checked_in, :people_attending
  # etc., etc.
end
```

What I'm wrangling with are two things:

1. How to define my mix-in such that a class variable magically springs into existence; and
2. How to access that variable both in my `ClassMethods` module and in the (for lack of a better term) instance methods part of the module.

Note that I've settled on a mix-in technique rather than inheritance because I will have `Validatable`, `Persistable`, `Serializable` and so on. Also, I know there are all sorts of validation and persistence layers available that are well tested and heavily used. This is a different beast and I really should know who to do this in my sleep, right?

Any Ruby wizards who can help me understand how to do this or suggest a different direction to approach this problem from, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the class variable, and adding this to the module `ClassMethod`:

```
def self.extended(klass)
  klass.instance_variable_set("@serializable_attrs", [])
end
```

And changing the double-`@` to single in `serializable`. And change `serialize!` to this:

```
self.class.instance_variable_get("@serializable_attrs").each{|a| do_something_with(a)}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was part way there when I thought, "this is too ugly." I'm happy to see it's just my imagination and that this is right.

Comment: @SteveRoss: Glad I could help. Just work out the value of `self` in your head. That's the key to Ruby metaprograming. Ruby never preforms any black magic, remember that.